# Updating an AWS Redshift table with Pandas update() via AWS Lambda - issues

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

Why the target table is not updated? I'm trying to do so from AWS Lambda and the target DB is the AWS Redshift. [image]

When I log the `original_table_df` updates is not applied in it, at all. Instead it has the same state as it has before the update operation.

When I initialize new DFs and do the same locally, it works.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i imagine its failing, try removing errors=ignore and possible the try except mechanism to see whats happening

Comment: No error occurred. Nothing has changed. @JonScott